# Is it safe to persist the device user's data in SQLite on Android after logout?

Tags: android, sqlite, security, session, logout

For example, if I have a messaging app, and I wish to make it so that people can log out and let their friend log on with the same device, is it safe to leave all of the existing messages in the database, as long as the oAuth token gets destroyed in the shared preferences?

I don't want to have to redownload the phone owner's messages each time a new user logs in?

If I was to leave it there, that means the person who borrowed the phone might be able to have their messages read, will it? Or is there a way I can encrypt them on the phone so that even if the sqlite3 db gets compromised, the messages can't be read?

I could make a check box on the login screen maybe that says "this is my phone" and that would allow for persistence on logout?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to store all data base on login user unique identifications so whenever your application will get from sqlite3 db then you have filter base on user unique identifications.

Second, you can easily encrypt Sqlite DB with library. More details : https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher

Comment: I can make a new database for each new user?

Comment: No need to create new db for each user but you have to put one field in table which can identifier user. So you can filter base on login user.

Comment: @Yoker You can make a different database for each user. I thin that's far simpler than putting all data from all users in the same database and then trying to federate it through queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQlite means someone can pull your database from your device and they can use it. In our normal way of coding we use SQlite database.

If you consider the security then SQLITE CIPHER is the better choice. Which is basically used to encrypt the database. So we have less tension about the data.

In your particular case don't delete data at the time of sign out. Whenever you fetch messages from database then use the WHERE Clause with user unique id. Which will help you to stop the new user see your old messages.

Comment: I would need a method of clearing old data, of friends that had used device a while ago, don't want to use up all the device owner's memory. 

Would it be sufficient to check on each login for any users that hadn't logged in within the last week, and delete all their data?

Comment: In that case you can delete your messages while log out. But you can't get the data next time you must need to download it

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is about keeping one user's data/messages separate from another user's data/messages, you can simply use a different SQLite database file for each user. You can design your `SQLiteOpenHelper` to take a username and use that as part of the name of the database file.

If your concern is about securing the data itself, then it's worth noting that files in your app's data directory (including databases) are private to your app and your app's process, they cannot be read by other apps' processes. In order for something else to read the file or to extract it using `adb pull`, root privilege is required.

Unless there is some really sensitive data in your database, I don't think root concerns are worth addressing. Relatively few users have rooted devices. But, if you have data that must be protected even in the most extreme cases, then you can look at using [SQLCipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher) to encrypt the database.